# Real Analysis HW Question involving continuity.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is two-to-one. Find an example of a two-to-one function and show that no such function can be continuous. I have had issues doing either of these. I feel it has something to do with $[a,b]$ being compact. So 1. I know that the continuous image of a compact set is compact, 2. continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous, and 3. I know sequential compactness and most other "equivalent" forms of continuity. Can anyone drop me a hint?

Comment: Do you know the extreme value theorem:  That a function on a compact set achieves its maximum and minimum?

Comment: yes? what do i get from that?

Comment: so assuming, for contradiction, that f is continuous, we can say there are two points whose image is an abs max and two whose image is the abs min. consider sequences maybe?

Comment: Yes, so you have to abs maxs and two abs mins.  If these alternate, the graph must go up and down too many times to just be $2$-$1$ (using the intermediate value theorem), so you can assume wlog they are ordered max, max, min, min.  Then, find the abs min between the two maxs and pick any $y$ value in between this restricted abs min and the two abs maxs.  Prove this $y$ value is hit at least 3 times - twice in between the two maxs and another time going from max to the abs min.

Comment: I hate the immediate feeling of stupidity that ensues when someone shows you something so obvious. Thank you a million Jason.

Comment: :-)  Once you have a less sketchy proof than I wrote above, you should answer your own question with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion for a different proof from the one Jason DeVito pointed out. It is not necessarily easier, but uses the nested intervals lemma, which may be a plus.

Suppose $f$ is continuous and 2-to-1. Let $$t = \frac12(\min_{[a,b]} f + \max_{[a,b]} f)$$  The set $\{x:f(x)=t\}$ consists of exactly two points, say $a_1$ and $b_1$ with $a_1<b_1$. On the interval $(a_1,b_1)$ we have either $f>t$ or $f<t$. Assume $f>t$ on this interval (the other case can be turned into this one by flipping $f$).

Let $$t_1 = \frac12(\min_{[a_1,b_1]} f + \max_{[a_1,b_1]} f)$$ Again, the set $\{x:f(x)=t_1\}$ consists of exactly two points, say $a_2$ and $b_2$ with $a_1<a_2<b_2<a_1$. This time, we know that on the interval $(a_2,b_2)$ the inequality $f>t_1 $ holds (why?). Continuing this process, we get a nested sequence of intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ such that $[a_n,b_n]=\{x:f(x)\ge t_{n-1}\}$. The intersection of these intervals is precisely the set of absolute  maxima of $f$ (why?), and being the intersection of nested intervals, it is either infinite or a single point.